# python lxml.html add space to element

Tags: python, html

I am parsing a web-page and getting the text content out of it by using the lxml.html `HTMLEElement text_content()` function. The problem is that the HTML itself doesn't have any whitespace and all new lines are indicated by the `<p>` tag. What I'd like to do is add newlines to all `<p>` elements so that when the text is output, I don't have lines concatenated together with no spaces.

I get the elements I need this way:

```
divs = body.cssselect('div')
```

Where the HTML looks like this:

```
<html><...><body><div><p>Text on one line.</p><p>Text on another line.</p></body></html>
```

I'd like to add `\n` to each `<p>` element in the divs that I get.

Thanks

Comment: Post the lxml code you're written and some sample HTML you're attempting to scrape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be easy:

```
p_elements = body.findall(".//p")
for element in p_elements:
    text = element.text
    element.text = "\n" + text
```